# How make apache server validate lack of basicConstraints extension in intermediate certificates

Tags: apache, ssl, x509certificate, client-certificates, cac

I'm using apache server as SSL terminator for mutual SSL authentication.

Is it possible to add some configuration to Apache server to validate if all  intermediate certificates (client certificate chain) - have  basicConstraints extension.

I saw such configuration when using Oracle Web server plug in with apache:

> **EnforceBasicConstraints**  - This parameter closes a security hole which existed with SSL certificate validation where certificate chains
>   with invalid V3 CA certificates would not be properly rejected. This
>   allowed certificate chains with invalid intermediate CA certificates,
>   rooted with a valid CA certificate to be trusted. X509 V3 CA
>   certificates are required to contain the BasicConstraints extension,
>   marked as being a CA, and marked as a critical extension. This
>   checking protects against non-CA certificates masquerading as
>   intermediate CA certificates.

The question is it possible to have such functionality without that plugin?

Thanks